# Show React Native (custom keyboard) component that is the same height as the system keyboard without layout shift

Tags: react-native

I am displaying a "custom keyboard" that is the same height as the system keyboard.
Is there a way to prevent the screen shifting down when:

- system keyboard is already shown
- button is clicked to show "custom keyboard" that is the same height as the system keyboard

and showing this "custom keyboard" when system keyboard is dismissed?

I have tried animations and state related to the system keyboard listeners etc.